# Pre-configured EC2 VPN AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn, amazon-ami

I have been google-ing around for the answer to this for that last hour or so but can't find anything on it. I would like to have pre-configured ami for AWS EC2 that will let me spin up an instance and ssh in and set user/pass for people to VPN though the instance. Of course my dream would be some sort of web interface for managing/monitoring/allocating VPN access but I assume that is far-fetched and would never be offered for free.

What I am looking for is this:
AMI running on micro instance
OpenVPN installed and ready to go
Little-no config needed

What I think that would look like is that I could start an instance of this ami, ssh in and add user/pass to OpenVPN and be using my instance as a VPN server (Using AWS's public IP) in less than 10 min without running countless commands to install all the needed programs.

There is a possibility that I am completely wrong in what I am trying to do and if that is the case just let me know I'm an idiot. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check this out Josh:

http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/cloudmachines/513-access-server-amazon-vpc.html

The AMI isn't currently available in US-WEST-2, so if you want to control resources in that region you'll have to hand build. But if you're running in US-WEST-1, then you can use this very easily, also, it comes with a decent front-end.

Comment: the link is broken :( any replacement links?

Answer (score 10):

It's not a pre-built API but I have published a startup script to setup an Amazon EC2 instance with IPSec/L2TP VPN. You can do it in less than 5 minutes, you dont even need to actually log into the machine.

The good thing with IPSec/L2TP: it works out of the box for most clients (tested with Mac OS Lion and Mountain Lion).

It is here: https://github.com/sarfata/voodooprivacy
And here: http://www.sarfata.org/posts/setting-up-an-amazon-vpn-server.md

Answer (score 3):

Here's a script I just made: It sets up a simple client certificate authenticated multiple concurrent users capable openvpn server on an Amazon Linux (red hat/centos based). Set up the EC2 virtual machine, download the script, run it, download the generated configuration files to your client, and start using the vpn.

https://github.com/viljoviitanen/setup-simple-openvpn